# About reading data using streams in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

On tutorial I found this example about reading data using streams

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I have couple questions:

1) Since one does `data+= chunk` this means the chunk is string right?
otherwise how would this concatenation work?

2) But if 1) is true and `chunk` is string, why was encoding not set?

3) How would you modify this example to read binary file? Surely the
`data+=chunk` concatenation would not work in this case if data is binary?

Can someone please clarify this confusions?

Comment: If it's a binary file, use a Buffer object to accumulate the data rather than a string.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok but was not it necessary to set encoding in this example to interpret data as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.createReadStream()` takes an optional second argument which is an options object where the encoding for reading the stream can be configured. If no encoding is set, then it defaults to utf8 string.  It took a while to find that info because it is not in the doc, but it is [in the code here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L82).

So, if you don't pass the encoding as a property of the `options` argument to `fs.createReadStream()`, then it defaults to `utf8`.  if you wanted to handle binary data, then you can configure the encoding to `null`.  Streams also have the ability to call the `.setEncoding(...)` method to specifically set their encoding, though it is normally set in the constructor for the stream since a stream usually doesn't change its encoding after being created.

So, the encoding for the stream determines whether you are passed a utf8 string or a buffer or some other encoding type of data.  And, if you had no encoding (e.g. binary), then you would be passed a `Buffer` object instead of a string when new data is available.

Comment: you mean typeof chunk would be buffer if it were binary file??

Comment: and since typeof chunk is string (it was converted to string by stream?) in my example javascript knows it and automatically uses correct overload of += operator?

Comment: @user200400 - The `chunk` argument would be a Buffer object if it was binary.  'chunk' is a string if it's utf8 encoding.  So, in your example, it's just adding two strings which is a normal string operation (not really an overload, per se).

Comment: ok but who converted chunk to string? The readStream? e.g. due to encoding

Comment: @user200400 -Yes, as I said, the readStream has an encoding property that determines how it interprets the data it gets.

Comment: ok, final question: in case I get Buffer object back, will it contain whole file contents? IMO no

Comment: @user200400 - Streams are not predictable for how much data they will give you on each `data` event.  For a small file, you may get the whole file on the first event or not.  If you want the whole file at once, then use `fs.readFile()`.